# Pass function as parameter (Lambda)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to understand Java 8's Lambda expressions. In the example, I want to parse a number of files. For each file, I need to create a new instance of the particular template (which is the same for all the files passed at a time).

If I understood it right, that's what Lambda expressions are good for.

Can anyone please explain to me in simple term how to pass the call to the template's constructor as a parameter? (So that it could be `new Template1()`, `new Template2()` and so on).

```
import java.io.File;

public class Parser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Parser(new File[]{});
  }

  Parser(File[] files) {
    for (File f : files) {
      // How can I pass this as a parameter?
      Template t = new Template1();
    }
  }

  public class Template {
    // Code...
  }

  public class Template1 extends Template {
    // Code...
  }

  public class Template2 extends Template {
    // Code...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [Supplier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and constructor [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Parser(new File[]{}, Template1::new);
}

Parser(File[] files, Supplier<Template> templateFactory) {
  for (File f : files) {
    Template t = templateFactory.get();
  }
}
```

The [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) type could be used for a one-argument constructor like `Template1(File)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Parser(new File[]{}, Template1::new);
}

Parser(File[] files, Function<File, Template> templateFactory) {
  for (File f : files) {
    Template t = templateFactory.apply(f);
  }
}
```

The Java 8 API provides a number of standard functional interfaces in the [java.util.function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package though these typically don't extend beyond two arguments. You can either use 3rd party nary functional interfaces (I made [some](http://mcdiae.github.io/kludje/artefacts/api/0.2/uk/kludje/fn/nary/package-summary.html) for [KludJe](http://kludje.uk/)) or write your own.

A custom implementation might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Parser(new File[]{}, Template1::new);
}

Parser(File[] files, TemplateFactory templateFactory) {
  for (File f : files) {
    Template t = templateFactory.createFrom(f);
  }
}

public static interface TemplateFactory {
  Template createFrom(File file);
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is an even cleaner syntax than I expected! Thanks a lot!

Comment: May I ask another question? What if the template's constructor takes a parameter, for example the file itself (which I don't know when the main method's called). Of course, I could use a setter method. But is there a way to pass a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: For a constructor with one argument you could swap Supplier for [Function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). See [java.util.function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) for standard functional interfaces but write your own single-abstract-method interface if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, McDowell. I've read [this](http://www.coffee-bytes.com/2013/11/26/understanding-method-refs/) carefully, but I think I'm overchallenged with this. Looks like I'll have to stick with the setters.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples.